# how to change the dimensions of multiple backgrounds of a single div elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have given multiple backgrounds to a single div in a webpage. I wanted that as I scroll down that the background-image(Stickman), which is at the front, should remain of the same size, and the background-image(Landscape), which is behind it, should zoom.
I want to keep the size of stickman less than the container size.

But in my code both the background images are getting zoomed, kindly help me with it.

Below is the code :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
 
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    var up=$(document).scrollTop();
                    var upperl=10;
                    var lowerl=500;
                    var a=0;
                    var b=$("#body1").width();
                    if(up<=upperl)
                    { 
                       a=b; 
                    }
                    else if(up>=upperl)
                    {
                        a=b+up;
                    }
                    

                    $("#backgroundslide").css("background-size", a+"px");
                  
                   
                     });
                     });
            </script>
        <style>
            body{
                color:white;
                top:0;
            margin:0;
            }
            #body1{
                width:100%;
                height:880px;
               position:relative;
            }
        #backgroundslide{
            background-image:url("http://www.downloadclipart.net/svg/18970-stickman-tired-svg.svg"),url("http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Silver-cliff.jpg");
            
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            
  background-size: 200px,cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom, top;
        }
        #a{
            margin-top:100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body1">
        <div id="backgroundslide">
           
            <h1>This is Heading</h1>
           
            <p id="a">Irure pariatur et est ullamco fugiat ut. Duis incididunt sint non nostrud ut enim irure veniam. Veniam veniam cillum Lorem adipisicing laboris id esse ullamco deserunt. Incididunt duis adipisicing anim sit nisi qui magna nisi nulla.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgot to set a value for the stickman.

```
$("#backgroundslide").css("background-size", '200px auto,' + a + "px");
```

See the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var up = $(document).scrollTop();
    var upperl = 10;
    var lowerl = 500;
    var a = 0;
    var b = $("#body1").width();
    if (up <= upperl) {
      a = b;
    } else if (up >= upperl) {
      a = b + up;
    }


    $("#backgroundslide").css("background-size", '200px auto,' + a + "px");


  });
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#body1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 880px;
  position: relative;
}

#backgroundslide {
  background-image: url("https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/151822.svg"), url("http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Silver-cliff.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 200px auto, cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom, top;
}

#a {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="body1">
  <div id="backgroundslide">

    <h1>This is Heading</h1>

    <p id="a">Irure pariatur et est ullamco fugiat ut. Duis incididunt sint non nostrud ut enim irure veniam. Veniam veniam cillum Lorem adipisicing laboris id esse ullamco deserunt. Incididunt duis adipisicing anim sit nisi qui magna nisi nulla.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you give me link where i can find a complete reference for these things(Manipulation of multiple background properties)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention in the question that , If i keep the length of the stickman less than the container size, then it expands to the container size, is there any way i can keep the size of the stick man constant